# Display data from a PHP query returning Json data, via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

When I run the code shown below on my website, I have the following error in my Chrome console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

jQuery:

```
    $('#SearchBtn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'request.administration.php',
            data: {id: $("#InputId").val()},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    console.log("not found");
                } else {
                    $("#InputFirstname").val(data[0]);
                    $("#InputLastname").val(data[1]);
                    $("#InputPhone").val(data[2]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE id=" . $_POST["id"];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $firstname = $row["firstname"];
            $lastname = $row["lastname"];
            $phone = $row["phone"];

            $values = array(
                $firstname,
                $lastname,
                $phone
            );
            json_encode($values);
        } else {
            echo "1";
        }
    }
```

As a matter of fact, I don't know how to display my firstname, lastname and phone number, from a Json function. I've read similar topics but I didn't get the answer to my question.

I did some checking before I came to you for help:
-the input ids are correct.
-the PHP creates the array correctly.
-when I run a console.log(data), nothing happens.

Thank you in advance to those who will be able to help me.

Comment: use echo json_encode

Comment: It's generally a good practice to always return data in the same type of format. Normally your code returns JSON (or would do, if you'd actually echoed it - see comment above). But if there's a problem, you're returning simply "1" without any format, which breaks this convention, and makes it harder for the client to know how to decode your data. Also, if the query fails for some reason, the PHP returns nothing at all, which will cause confusion at the client-side, and leave you without any info on the server side with which to trace the error either. Just something to think about.

Comment: Also: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: And a small point about efficiency: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $firstname = $row["firstname"];
            $lastname = $row["lastname"];
            $phone = $row["phone"];

            $values = array(
                $firstname,
                $lastname,
                $phone
            );
            json_encode($values);` could be shortened to `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo json_encode($row);`.

Comment: And then the JS code `$("#InputFirstname").val(data[0]);
                    $("#InputLastname").val(data[1]);
                    $("#InputPhone").val(data[2]);` can be changed to `$("#InputFirstname").val(data.firstname);
                    $("#InputLastname").val(data.lastname);
                    $("#InputPhone").val(data.phone);` to read the named values directly - much shorter, more maintainable, and clearer too (especially in the JS where you can see exactly which field matches which).